# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when running Angular with .Net Core Api in Docker

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a communication issue between an angular front-end app and a dotnet core 6 web api.

Both are running inside Docker with Mariadb database.
The communication between the api and the database works fine.

The front-end is running on port 4200 and is accessible
The back-end is running on port 4000
[image]

I get the following  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error
[image]

I have checked the stats on the back-end api and the network I/O does indicate some communication, but there is nothing on the logs.

The dockerfile for the back-end

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:4000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["mealAllergensApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "mealAllergensApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "mealAllergensApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "mealAllergensApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mealAllergensApi.dll"]
```

[image]

Comment: The backend should also be accessible, not only the frontend. It's your browser that is firing the requests to your backend, and not your frontend container.

Comment: On the container API logs are there any requests logged? Have you set up the CORS?

Answer (score 0):

I changed every reference to 'localhost' in my asp.net core API to 'host.docker.internal' and voilà, the front could communicate with the back with each one of them being in separate containers.